# Multiple JComboBox Event Handling in Same Class

Tags: java, swing

I have two JComboBox and one button. I am trying to do that if I select an item from the two combo box individually and press the button called search. Then the two selected items from the two combo box will save in a new two separate string.

Please anyone help me to solve the problem.

Here is the code snippet

```
//here is the strings that in the combo box
String lc[] = {"Kolabagan-Dhaka", "Gabtoli-Dhaka", "Fakirapul-Dhaka", "Shaymoli-Dhaka"};
String rc[] = {"Banani-Bogra", "Rangpur","Shatrasta-Bogra"};

//here is my two jcombo box
JComboBox lcCombo = new JComboBox(lc);
JComboBox rcCombo = new JComboBox(rc);
// here is my search button
JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this. The first is to have one class that implements `ActionListener` and in the implementation, check the source (`ActionEvent.getSource()`). Based on which component sourced the event, you take the appropriate action.

The other option (and my preference) is to create an `ActionListener` for each component that requires one. You can use anonymous classes if you don't want to explicitly define one for each case. This way each listener knows exactly what component caused the event and what action to take.

Example:

```
JComboBox lcCombo = new JComboBox(lc);
lcCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    //do left stuff
  }
});
JComboBox rcCombo = new JComboBox(rc);
rcCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    //do right stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I think I understood. I will let you know if gone throw this.

Comment: @user1431631: Check the example to see what I mean by the second option.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on unholysampler, once you have the `ActionListener` working you can use `lcCombo.getSelectedIndex()` to check which item has been selected.